This question is about using the correct pronoun
Which of the below sentences is correct:

People who think they are right are confident.

or:

People those who think they are right are confident.


In this sentence:

People who think they are right are confident.

'who' is a relative pronoun because it introduces a relative clause, or adjective clause, about people. It connects to the previously mentioned 'people'.
'those' is a determiner, and a pronoun. It's the plural of that, and can be used to replace 'people' or 'those people'.
The following are all correct:

People who think they are right are confident.


Those people who think they are right are confident.


Those who think they are right are confident.

The following is not correct because 'those' is redundant in this word order:

People those who...


The first is normal usage.
The relative clause who think they are right has antecedent People.
Edit 2
In

People those who think they are right are confident.

the OP may have intended to treat those who think they are right as appositive.
This construction would be unusual without bracketing commas as the appositive is long. Appositives, except for very short ones, are usually set off by a bracketing comma pair.
With the commas added, those who think they are right  becomes parenthetical and functions as the appositive of People.
People, those who think they are right, are confident.
This construction though valid is quite unlikely with the given text.
(The following section from my original answer is shifted to the back as it is unlikely to be the OP’s intended meaning.)
Another way to use the second example is to add a comma and paragraph it as shown below, but I doubt it is the OP’s intention to write this way:

People,


Those who think they are right are confident.

Here People is in the vocative case.

You'd actually need two commas (or brackets, or dashes), to offset the higlighted parenthetical element in People, those who think they are right, are confident, because it's a parenthetical element - which is effectively in apposition to the preceding word People.

Thanks, @FumbleFingers.   I've added your point.

In a situation like this I think it's important that users should be aware of what is or isn't "syntactically valid" separately from what is or isn't idiomatically likely in their specific context. I'm guessing you got downvotes from people who focus exclusively on the latter distinction, but I think you make the point abundantly clear with I doubt it is the OP’s intention to write this way.

...It's quite possible the OP has actually encountered such "apposition" usages, but doesn't realize how unlikely the form is in the specific example context. Imho it's potentially discouraging to be told Your example text is completely wrong (you know nothing), as opposed to Your example text is "valid, but unlikely" (you've learned something, but there's a point of detail you should be aware of).

Thanks, @FumbleFingers.   For the example with the vocative expression, as I already stated I doubt ...  there's hence not much I can do.  I don't think I should delete that construction.  As for the example with the appositive, I've added the qualification that it's quite unlikely.

Well, when learners ask whether some (invalid AND/OR ridiculously unlikely) construction is valid, people sometimes ask Why do you think that might be valid? Which doesn't always get a meaningful response, but quite often a much better Answer can be posted if you know why the OP thought something might be valid. After all, if a young Anglophone child says Mum buyed me a sweet or I goed to the toilet, what they're saying might not be right, but it's clear evidence they've already learned how regular verbs work!

Thanks a lot, @FumbleFingers.
